# AlarmManager doesn't fire

Tags: java, android, push-notification, alarmmanager

my note app should remember my users with a notification at their note at a specific date and time the user had set. My Problem is that I don't get the notification at the set time.
This is my alarmManager.class (Here I create my Alarms)

```
public class alarmManager {

    public static void createAlarm(long timeInMillis, int requestCode, Intent i) {
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.context, requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        getAlarmManager().set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pi);
    }

    public static void deleteAlarm(Intent i, int requestCode) {
        if (doesPendingIntentExist(MainActivity.context, i, requestCode)) {
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.context, requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
            pi.cancel();
            getAlarmManager().cancel(pi);
        }
    }

    private static AlarmManager getAlarmManager() {
        return (AlarmManager) MainActivity.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    private static boolean doesPendingIntentExist(Context context, Intent i, int requestCode) {
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        return pi != null;
    }
}
```

When the user creates a new note this lines get fired (They send everything is needed to my alarmManager.class)

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.context, NotificationService.class);
        i.putExtra(NotificationService.i_UID, id);
        i.putExtra(NotificationService.i_TEXT, title);
        i.putExtra(NotificationService.i_CONTENT, content);
        i.putExtra(NotificationService.i_REMINDEDATE, mUserReminderDate);
        i.putExtra(NotificationService.i_REPEAT, repeatAlarmSelectedOption);
        alarmManager.createAlarm(mUserReminderDate.getTime(), id.hashCode(), i);
```

When everything works the NotificationService.class should get called at the chosen time. (Here the notification should show to the user)

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {
    public static final String i_UID = "uuid";
    public static final String i_TEXT = "title";
    public static final String i_CONTENT  = "content";
    public static final String i_REMINDEDATE = "remindeDate";
    public static final String i_REPEAT = "repeatAlarm";

    private String mTodoText, mTodoContent, mTodoUUID;
    private Date mTodoDate;
    private int mTodoRepeat;
    private Intent processIntent;

    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotificationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.processIntent = intent;
        mTodoText = intent.getStringExtra(i_TEXT);
        mTodoContent = intent.getStringExtra(i_CONTENT);
        mTodoUUID = intent.getStringExtra(i_UID);
        mTodoDate = (Date) intent.getSerializableExtra(i_REMINDEDATE);
        mTodoRepeat = intent.getIntExtra(i_REPEAT, 0);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(mTodoText)
                .setContentText(mTodoContent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo_transparent_bg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .build();

        manager.notify(100, notification);
    }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. No errors. No notification. Nothing.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What have you found out in debugging? Which part, exactly, is failing? The `createAlarm()` call? The alarm actually being set? The `Service` running? The alarm firing on time? Have you double-checked the `timeInMillis` you're setting, against the current time – `System.currentTimeMillis()` – to make sure the alarm time you've figured is reasonable? Do you have a `<service>` element in your manifest for `NotificationService`?

Comment: @MikeM. I don't know how to debug it. The only thing I can say about that is that there is no fatal error shown. Yes in the manifest I added all things correctly. But wait. What do you mean with `System.currentTimeMillis()`? I only use: `mUserReminderDate.getTime()`

Comment: OK, you're going to have to learn basic debugging skills; e.g., determining exactly how and where an app fails, utilizing your IDE's debugger, tweaking values to expose behaviors, etc. This, as a general topic, is far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, so I would ask that you do some research, testing, and just overall investigation into solving your issue first, then pose your questions as specific, detailed issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is when you create a `PendingIntent`:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.context, requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

To be absolutely sure, schedule an alarm, then run from `adb` following command:
`adb shell dumpsys alarm` and search for your `PendingIntent`. If you find it, schedule one more time alarm and run command one more time. Look again for your pending intent and make sure it is a new one and try to search for this previous scheduled. If it is problem with `PendingIntent` you will find only the newest `PendingIntent`.

**Solution:**
Since `AlarmManger` while comparing `PendingIntents` doesn't compare extra data passed it, but compares request code, data, action and categories you need to change one of them every time you schedule a new alarm. My suggestion is to pass `uri` from database to every new scheduled `PendingIntent`. That will make each of them uniqal so the older one won't be cancelled when a new scheduled. To sum up, to argument `i` in your code call method `setData()` and pass uri as an argument. You can do it in a method or from a class where method is being called. It may look like that:

```
 public static void createAlarm(long timeInMillis, int requestCode, Intent i, Uri uri) {
       i.setData(uri)
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.context, requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        getAlarmManager().set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pi);
    }
```

Comment: No that doesn't help me.

Comment: Have you checked if your pending intents are scheduled?